# installing three operating systems on mirrored volume

Tags: raid, boot

I have 2 mirrored hard disks in my server(ASUS TS500-e4). Then I have created 3 partitions on mirrored volume and installed 2003 server on 1st partition and 2008 R2 on 2nd partition. Then I tried to install the 2012 server on 3rd partition.

The problem is after the installation, the mirror was unavailable and displayed:

```
"no operating system found" message on the screen.
```

So I disabled RAID option in the BIOS and reboot the server. After rebooted  the server the boot selection menu displayed my installed operating systems. So I tried to boot them. Only the 2012 server booted successfully and other operating systems were not booted(restart the server when booting) I want to know what is the reason for it?

Comment: Why are you multi-booting a *server*?

Answer (score 3):

That's a pretty old server so finding details was hard but essentially it's what we call 'Fake-RAID' - i.e. it requires OS help to work. Thus if the array is only partially managed by the BIOS but mostly by the OS then trying to get one array to be managed by three different OS's is going to be hard/impossible. It's for this reason why pro's almost exclusively shun this kind of RAID for proper, fully-managed-by-the-controller RAID - it's OS-independent so you can do what you like with it partition-wise.

If you want to do any more digging around on this then you're probably best to search for 'fake-RAID' as there are a lot of people like yourself who've not come across the difference and problems until now, so there should be a lot to read.